# Align QScrollArea

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am putting on a QScrollArea a QLabel. Then I put the image on the QLabel. When I zoom in on the image, it moves left and up because the QScrollArea is so aligned. How to make it so that the increase occurs towards the center? Here's the code I'm using:

```
import sys
import cv2
import imutils
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("gui.ui", self)

        self.image = None
        self.height = None

        self.ui.openIm.clicked.connect(self.load)
        self.ui.zoomIn.clicked.connect(self.on_zoom_in)
        self.ui.zoomOut.clicked.connect(self.on_zoom_out)

    def on_zoom_in(self):
        self.height += 100
        self.resize_image()

    def on_zoom_out(self):
        self.height -= 100
        self.resize_image()

    def resize_image(self):
        scaled_pixmap = self.orig.pixmap().scaledToHeight(self.height)
        self.orig.setPixmap(scaled_pixmap)

    def load(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Select File')
        self.image = cv2.imread(str(filename[0]))
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(self.image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.image = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], frame.strides[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.ui.orig.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.image))
        self.height = self.image.height()
        self.ui.res.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.image))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dlgMain = MyWin()
    dlgMain.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Below is the gui.ui file code which I am using to connect to Python code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>420</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_4">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="openIm">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Load</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="3" column="0">
       <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>20</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1" rowspan="4">
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
        <item>
         <widget class="QScrollArea" name="areaOrig">
          <property name="layoutDirection">
           <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
           <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
           <enum>QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustIgnored</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="widgetResizable">
           <bool>true</bool>
          </property>
          <property name="alignment">
           <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
          </property>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
           <property name="geometry">
            <rect>
             <x>0</x>
             <y>0</y>
             <width>154</width>
             <height>556</height>
            </rect>
           </property>
           <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
            <item row="0" column="0">
             <widget class="QLabel" name="orig">
              <property name="text">
               <string/>
              </property>
              <property name="alignment">
               <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </widget>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QScrollArea" name="areaRes">
          <property name="widgetResizable">
           <bool>true</bool>
          </property>
          <property name="alignment">
           <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
          </property>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents_2">
           <property name="geometry">
            <rect>
             <x>0</x>
             <y>0</y>
             <width>153</width>
             <height>556</height>
            </rect>
           </property>
           <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
            <item row="0" column="0">
             <widget class="QLabel" name="res">
              <property name="text">
               <string/>
              </property>
              <property name="alignment">
               <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </widget>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="0">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="zoomIn">
        <property name="text">
         <string>ZoomIn</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="0">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="zoomOut">
        <property name="text">
         <string>ZoomOut</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: share the gui.ui

Comment: @Alex no, you should not use external resources (especially if they require authentication), the file must be embedded in the question.

Comment: @musicamante, how can I do this?

Comment: @Alex it's just an XML file, open it with a basic plain text editor.

Comment: @musicamante, right?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the "alignment", but with the fact that the position of widgets is always based on their top left corner, according to the parent's coordinate system.

Unfortunately, you cannot set the scroll bar positions right after the contents are resized, because it takes an unspecified amount of "time" to the scroll area to adapt its contents and then finally update the scroll bars with the new range.

A *theoretical* solution could be to ensure that the current event queue is cleared and *then* update the scroll bars according to the requirement.

This could be achieved with the following :

```
    while QApplication.hasPendingEvents():
        QApplication.processEvents()
    vBar = self.areaRes.verticalScrollBar()
    if vBar.maximum():
        vBar.setValue(vBar.maximum() * .5)
    hBar = self.areaRes.horizontalScrollBar()
    if hBar.maximum():
        hBar.setValue(hBar.maximum() * .5)
```

Unfortunately, while the above works, you should **not** do it, because it's not good for two important reasons:

- `hasPendingEvents` is obsolete (and deprecated since Qt6) due to problems with race conditions of threads and should *not* be used anymore;
- always scrolling to the center is a bad choice from the user's point of view: if the image is scrolled to the bottom, zooming will *always* center the scroll area, which is very annoying;

The *proper* solution is to use the scroll bar's [`rangeChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#rangeChanged) signal, and update the current value based on a *ratio* of the previous range, computed using `currentRange * (previousValue / previousRange)`.

To achieve this, the current ratio shall be stored *before* the range is changed and then stored again, but this can become a bit too complex for both scroll bars, so a better solution is to create a new subclass for the scroll bars that implements the concept on its own:

This approach has lots of benefits:

- the proportional position is always maintaned also when the scroll area is resized;
- a custom default ratio can be set (for instance, to always center the scroll area when zooming in after zooming out to a full view);
- it can be further implemented to provide custom behavior (for instance, *actually* based on the scroll area alignment);

This is how the class would be:

```
class KeepPositionScrollBar(QScrollBar):
    defaultRatio = .5
    ratio = .5
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.rangeChanged.connect(self.restoreRatio)
        self.valueChanged.connect(self.updateRatio)

    def restoreRatio(self):
        absValue = (self.maximum() - self.minimum()) * self.ratio
        self.setValue(round(self.minimum() + absValue))

    def updateRatio(self):
        if self.maximum() - self.minimum():
            absValue = self.value() - self.minimum()
            self.ratio = absValue / (self.maximum() - self.minimum())
        else:
            self.ratio = self.defaultRatio
```

Then you just have to install the scroll bars to the view(s):

```
class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("gui.ui", self)
        self.areaRes.setVerticalScrollBar(
            KeepPositionScrollBar(QtCore.Qt.Vertical, self.areaRes))
        self.areaRes.setHorizontalScrollBar(
            KeepPositionScrollBar(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self.areaRes))
```

Unrelated notes:

- keeping a reference to the `ui` is pointless, as it's only used during the setup phase, you can access all ui elements directly from `self`: `self.orig`, `self.res`, etc.; you can just call `uic.loadUi("gui.ui", self)` without assigning it, as I've done above;
- unless very special types of images files are used, Qt imaging plugins are perfectly capable of handling almost any standard image file and color format, so you don't normally need to use cv for that; also, the path returned by the file dialog is already a string, no need to do `str()`: `self.image = QPixmap(filename[0])`;
- you should check if the path is not empty (when the file dialog is cancelled) before trying to load the image;
- `self.height` is an existing standard *dynamic* property for all widgets, you should not overwrite it with something else;
- using `self.height -= 100` is wrong, as it could return a negative size, which would make the image null; you should at least ensure that the value is greater than 0 or possibly use a proportional ratio;
- when you are resizing the image, you're doing `self.orig.setPixmap`, which is wrong, since you're overwriting the same image you're using as source for the resizing every time you zoom: the result is that you try to zoom out and in a few times, the image becomes completely pixelated; you probably want to do `self.res.setPixmap` (or use the original `self.image` instead), so that the source is always kept;

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Henceforth, I will avoid unnecessary ui in my code. I use OpenCV because in the future I am going to process images using it. About checking self.filename - I don't know how. self.height removed outside of functions. Regarding self.height - = 100, I don't know how to replace it yet. And about the latter, I understand that you should always start from the original image, but I don't know how to implement it. I would also like to note that vertical scrolling does not work in your code. Maybe I did something wrong, but I just copied your code.

Comment: 1. to check if the file name is valid, just do `if not filename[0]: return`; 2. use a scale ratio (start by 1), then when zooming in or out first multiply the ratio by a fixed value (for instance: `self.ratio *= 1.25` for zoom in `self.ratio *= .8` for zoom out) and then you can find the new height using `newHeight = self.image.height() * self.ratio`; 3. since you're loading the original as `self.image`, always use that as source: `scaled = self.image.scaledToHeight(newHeight)` `self.res.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(scaled))`; 4. I don't know why vertical scrolling doesn't work, I just tested->

Comment: -> again and it works fine. Note that I set both scroll bars for the `areaRes`, maybe you're still setting the pixmap for `self.orig`, so you should clarify if you want to actually set the pixmap in it (and then you need to set the new scroll bars for it too, but they have to be correctly created using `self.areaOrig` as parent, not `self.areaRes`) or use `self.res` as suggested, which makes more sense, since `orig` is the *original* image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! After some thought, I decided to use QGraphicsView for my own purposes. It turned out to be much more convenient.

Comment: @Alex well, yes, that's usually the best choice whenever image visualization is considered the main purpose. Be aware, anyway, that the graphics view framework is as much powerful as it's complex: I strongly urge you to do **a lot** of research and studying on the documentation, starting with its main classes: QGraphicsView (and the inherited QAbstractScrollArea), QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsItem. All of them have a *lot* of features and functions, and it's *really* important to be aware of them.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I try hard. But the documentation is very difficult for me. I've been learning Qt for a few months now, but I still feel like I lack basic knowledge. In the reviews on YouTube, everything is very superficial, but in the documentation everything is very difficult :) Therefore, I am slowly moving forward.

Comment: @Alex I can understand that: Qt has a very long and steep learning curve. I've been using it for more than 5 years and I still find myself surprised to realize things I didn't know about. The documentation also takes some time to get used to, but it's just a matter of habit, the more you use it, the more you understand it; also, trying to read the source code is **really** useful and educational (again, it takes some time to be able to do it): python requires you to always use good syntax, which makes understanding *code logic* easier, even if it's in other languages. Just keep going :-)

Comment: About the youtube tutorials, I cannot say a lot, besides the fact that I have always avoided them: they can be handy at first, but they are also very, **very** limited. Also, unfortunately, there's ***a lot*** of people that believe they can do tutorials because they *think* they know what they are doing, but I have found lots of them providing very bad (if not terrible) suggestions, because they don't realize what *learning* means or because they just don't *really* know the toolkit/language they're trying to teach about. So, I strongly suggest you to be very skeptic about what they tell you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will continue to learn Qt :) And I will try to devote less time to YouTube.

Comment: No, don't ignore them: they *are* useful, even if they *do* tell wrong things. I myself watch them from time to time, as I'm interested in how other people do things. The important (and difficult) thing is that you have to learn to tell apart whether they're suggesting things while ensuring that *you* are aware of the consequences or not. Teaching (even by providing an answer on SO) is important as it's difficult, and that's why most of us take **a lot** of time in providing answers, sometimes even *hours*. But we can also learn from *other people's mistakes*, including teachers.

Comment: I think I get it. This is like an example with placing an image on a QLabel :) It turned out to be more correct to use it for QGraphicsView, but on YouTube they showed a QLabel.